# Do the cards in the shop depend on the arena you are in when the shop refreshes?

Tags: clash-royale

Will cards from a higher arena than you appear in the card shop, or will only cards from the arena you are in (or below) when it refreshes be available to purchase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Like every other option for cards, the shop also takes into account what arena you are on at the moment.

If on your main screen it shows Arena 6, there is no way you'd be able to buy the Royal Giant or the three musketeers with gold from the shop.

Comment: Providing a link to the wiki would help cement this answer.

Comment: @Jcraft153 I am aware and I generally look for one, but in this case I couldn't find a proper link, so my experience from before the world launch and "I read it somewhere" will hopefully be enough.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is correct. If you do find a link that confirms this though, please add it. :)