# Legendary arena change

Tags: clash-royale

Since legendary arena has changed to hog mountain, are we still able to buy legendaries in that arenas shop or will you have to move up to arena 11?

Comment: Can't prove it to you, but I am currently at Hog Mountain and have a legendary Lava Hound in my shop

Answer (score 1):

They will appear regardless of the trophy count, as long as you're in arena 10

source

[image: profile]
[image: shop]

Comment: I suspected this was the actual answer, but I wanted to ask, did you drop below 3000 before or after the shop refreshed?  I can confirm that the shop **only** changes at refresh, so if you were above 3000 when it refreshed the above may not be perfect proof since your shop refreshed about 8 hours before (although still very good effort and thanks).

Comment: it refreshed last night, and i haven't played ladder in forever as you can see with my lack of chests

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you will still be able to find "Legendary" cards in the shop.**

This hasn't ever been set by the arena status, but your **trophy count.** This meant that if you were in the legendary arena but only with, for example, 2990 trophies, you still could be able to find "Legendary" cards in the shop. It was always set to **status = "Arena 10"**.

Hope that helped.

Comment: The core "yes" answer I agree with.  Are you sure about the trophy limit though?  In all other cases the Arena is used to determine "perks" associated with that level.  It seems very odd that they would use Trophy count for this specific case.

Comment: @EBongo As seen in the release notes, as JockE's answer is showing, they say "Legendary Cards will still appear in your Shop at 3000 Trophies".

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I think that's still subject to interpretation without definitive proof.  Since chests, donates, and [cards per arena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262587/do-the-cards-in-the-shop-depend-on-the-arena-you-are-in-when-the-shop-refreshes) are tied to an arena based system, it would seem odd for them to code the shop differently.

Comment: I will try to email the developers and they will hopefully send some info

Comment: This is inccorrect

Comment: @bleh you would have to get some evidence about that I guess..

Comment: look up at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Answer: **Yes**. 
 According to the [release notes](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/update-new-leagues-clan-battles-and-more) under "New Arena":
*Legendary Cards will still appear in your Shop at 3000 Trophies*.